# Which git GUIs will show the command line command that will be executed?

Tags: git, user-interface, command-line

I use git bash, git gui, and gitk. I would find it very helpful if git GUI would show the command line command that will be executed based on the GUI inputs. Are there any git GUIs that do this? Which ones?

Comment: I don't know of any, but it's a very interesting idea both for learning and debugging. The opaqueness of GIt GUIs is amongst the reasons I don't recommend them except for visualization. They might have a log or debug mode. Though some might be using [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) and thus have no git commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) it will show you the full output.
You can set it to be the default under the `Tools > Options`.

---

[image]

[image]